# Shapefile to KML Conversion Problems in QGIS 2.6.1 on Mac

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, kml, mac

I am currently using QGIS 2.6.1 on a Mac with OS 10.9.5.  I am trying to export a shapefile using QGIS to KML format.  I am having success with the export but the data is skewed halfway across the world and is wrong.  Is anyone else having this problem?

Here is my data before the export in shapefile format (WGS84)

[image]

Now here is my data after the shapefile to kml conversion

[image]

These lines wrap halfway across the world

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard about that problem yet but there can be basically just two things wrong.
Either the projection of the shapefile is not correct or you messed up the "save as" function with any inputs apart from what is set default. i tried it with a random shp file with same version and for me it works. So check your settings.

Comment: g07kore, thanks for your response.  I have checked the projection of the shapefile... it started out in NAD83 State Plane and I even reprojected it to WGS84 and tried it (even though I have the CRS settings on 'Automatically enable on the fly reprojection if layers have different CRS') and I wasn't successful exporting in either projection.  I have also tried using the default settings as well and I am still having the same problem.

Comment: kml export always goes to WGS84 to work with spherical mercator (Google Earth Globe)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, KML only support WGS84, that is EPSG:4326. In QGIS 2.18, if you use save as to transfer shape to KML, not matter what output coordinate system you selected, the output KML file is always WGS84.

Answer (score 0):

you might try "EPSG 3857, WGS84/Pseudo Mercator"